# coldfusion can an array be a value in a structure?

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, structure

Working in ColdFusion, I have a structure called botmsg.  For each key in botmsg there are 3 values, each having a different use.  Is it possible for the value of a key to be an array?

If so, how do you put an array in there?  Would it be

```
<cfset botmsg.key = myarray>  or
<cfset botmsg.key = #myarray#>
```

Or what?  And if that can be done, how do I retrieve the values in the array.  If I want myarray[1] when I reference botmsg.key, how do I indicate it?  Would it be

```
botmsg.key[1]
```

I realize I could use a list instead of an array, and convert it to an array when I retrieve it; but I think it would be cleaner and safer to have an array to begin with.

I have looked for information about this, but haven't been able to find anything out there.  Yet, I'm sure I've seen a structure which has an array or even another structure as a value.

Comment: Yes you can have an array in a struct.  Your first `cfset` command will work.  Regarding retrieving the values, use assciative array notation - `botmsg[key][1]`.

Comment: (Edit) Was there a problem when you tried it? Also, unless data order is the central focus, a structure would make for more intuitive code than an array. For example much easier to understand the variable preferences.myfavorites.songName than preferences[1][2]. https://trycf.com/gist/32a86a69afdb808a318902c7160fb708/lucee5?theme=monokai

Comment: @Betty Mock please add some example data to your struct or array, so we can better understand what you are exactly trying to achieve.

Comment: @DanBracuk -- that is exactly the information I needed.

Comment: @SOS I didn't try it because I didn't know what the syntax might be.  Making the array a structure is a good idea.

Comment: Trying something and throwing an error is a pretty effective way to learn correct syntax.

Comment: @DanBracuk -- yes I try a lot of things and get lots of errors.  I have a set of programs called frag1, frag2, etc. for those tryouts.  And when something works, I save it as a program called demosomething.cfm.  But usually I have some clue about what the syntax might be.  In this case I may have felt more clueless than I actually was, but my bafflement was why I asked.

Comment: @DanBracuk - You should post an answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfset botmsg = structNew()>
<cfset myarray = arrayNew(1)>
<cfset myarray[1] = 10>
<cfset botmsg.key = myarray>
<cfoutput>#botmsg.key[1]#</cfoutput><!--- will output 10 --->
```

Answer (score 0):

hope it will help

```
<cfset botmsg.key = myArray>
<cfset firstValue = botmsg.key[1]>
<cfset secondValue = botmsg.key[2]>
<cfset botmsg = {}> <!--- Create an empty structure --->

<cfset myArray = ["Value1", "Value2", "Value3"]> <!--- Create an array --->

<cfset botmsg.key = myArray> <!--- Associate the array with the key "key" in the structure --->

<cfoutput>
    First Value: #botmsg.key[1]#<br>
    Second Value: #botmsg.key[2]#<br>
</cfoutput>
```